# Dividing a 16 bit number by 2 [PIC microcontroller]

Tags: pic

If a 16 bit value is stored (in a pic microcontroller) as a High byte and Low byte, how do you go about dividing them by 2? How can a 16 bit number be rotated right?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post. Yes it can be rotated right but I do not get the idea of rotating a 16 bit number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dividing a 16-bit number by two is equivalent to shifting the number right by a single bit<sup>*</sup>. Clear the carry flag, rotate the higher byte right through the carry, and then rotate the lower byte right through the carry. You can find code for it [here](http://www.mcmanis.com/chuck/robotics/projects/pic-16bit.htm):

```
LSR16   MACRO   VAR16
    BCF     STATUS, C       ; Clear carry
    RRF     (VAR16)+1,F     ; Rotate high byte right
    RRF     (VAR16),F       ; Rotate low byte right
    ENDM
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Of course this is an integer division: when odd numbers are divided by two, the `0.5` is truncated.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try and get back if there's any problem.

Comment: You can add the carry bit if rounding is important.  You'll have to carry that up to the higher byte as well.